# Update query subtract same sale model rows from stock table?

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables:

```
> Sale 
--------------------------------------------------------
 ID      customer       model                    qty
--------------------------------------------------------
 1         Ali          H46                      1
 1         aslam        H46                      1
 1         kasif        H46                      1
 1         umer         H46                      1
 1         naveed       H46                      1
---------------------------------------------------------

> Stock

---------------------------------------------------------
ID        model               qty
---------------------------------------------------------
1         H46                 40
1         H47                 30
1         H48                 20
1         H49                 60
1         H50                 20
---------------------------------------------------------
```

MySQL query I applied

```
UPDATE sale AS T1
INNER JOIN stock T2
    ON T1.model = T2.model
SET T2.qty = (T2.qty - T1.qty)
```

In result in stock table only one qty update doesn't total sale qty minus from stock table.

I want all sale qty minus from stock. But my query result return 1 record update in stock.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [MySQL update statement match only the first row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265357/mysql-update-statement-match-only-the-first-row). The bottom line seems to be that MySql will only update the same row once and you will have to use an aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to join to an aggregate of the `Sale` table:

```
UPDATE stock st
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT model, SUM(qty) AS qty
    FROM sale
    GROUP BY model
) s
    ON st.model = s.model
SET
    st.qty = st.qty - s.qty;
```

An inner join update (rather than a left join update) should be fine here, since models which had zero sales would not require updating the stock anyway.

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen thanks this query work on match model's ?

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data which explains this requirement.